# Manjaro installation stuck on "Reached target graphical interface"

Tags: linux, boot, dual-boot, manjaro, gpu

I just purchased a new PC with Windows 10 installed on it. The PC has two SSD cards, one for the Windows and one empty which I want to install Manjaro-Linux on. And load it all with the Dual Boot.

To install Manjaro I'm using a USB. I used Rufus to do so.

I guess the error is due to the GPU. I'm using the RTX 3060ti and for CPU I use i7 10700F. I wrote those in case the problem has to do with either of them...

*I must mention that the installation of the Manjaro did work on my previous PC. On my previous PC, I divided my HDD into half and installed Manjaro on the empty half.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a couple of weeks later, It worked. I believe it has to do with the version I installed and the GPU at the time, it didn't have the graphical support. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

If during your installation process you had a working internet connection and flagged `install third-party drivers`, your GPU should not be a problem.

Take a look if you can switch to a new TTY with `alt+F2`. If you're able to do so, login and execute `journalctl -xe` and look for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Rufus showed a few bad blocks in the USB. Changing the USB stick worked for me.